# More Announcements link it dosen't work -- How to edit it?

Tags: error, url

Quick one...Is there anyone who knows how to edit the URL of "more announcements" button in webpart?
Basically i've inserted Announcements on homepage and i allow just 5 announcements. After these 5 announcements an MORE ACCOUNCEMENTS link appear, but if i click on it, it's goes on same page, nothing happen.

Comment: You can change the view to use batching instead. Just edit the view and it should be under the Item Limit section.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by creating new Announcements app. It's seems like something was wrong with the other app.